# How I know if I using Bouncy Castle from jar or the one implemented in Android?

Tags: android, bouncycastle

How I know if I using Bouncy Castle from jar or the one implemented in Android?
I've downloaded from https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html and add jar to my Android Studio project.
How can I check if I am using it (The one I downloaded)?

Comment: You could try using SpongyCastle instead

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Because is... fill please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For at least the last several versions Android has fixed the namespace conflict by renaming the bouncycastle classes they use to com.android.**. I'm not exactly sure when this occurred, but looking at the source code repository at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/+refs suggests the change happened starting with Ice Cream Sandwich -- API level 14.

I'm not sure what they did about the string-based provider lookups, e.g. `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5PADDING", "BC")`. However, every `getInstance()` method in the JCE also has a version where you can explicitly specify the Provider class, e.g. `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5PADDING", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())` which eliminates any ambiguity.

Comment: Per [Spongy Castle issue #34](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34), it would appear this change was introduced with Android 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The Android platform bundle a restricted subset of Bouncy Castle, and will be selected by default if you set the provider by the name "BC". (not if you do it by class as James indicates)

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA","BC")
```

Alternatives to use your own cryptographic provider:

**1 Incluye your own version of BouncyCastle**

Include bouncycastle's jars, remove the bundled provider and add new one.

```
Security.removeProvider("BC");
BouncyCastleProvider bc = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.insertProviderAt(bc,1);
```

**2 Use Spongycastle**:

SpongyCastle is the official repackage of BouncyCastle for Android. https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/. Include the dependency and use "SC" instead of "BC"

```
 Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA","SC")
```

> **Why?**
>
> The Android platform unfortunately ships with a cut-down version of Bouncy Castle - as well as being crippled, it also makes installing an updated version of the libraries difficult due to classloader conflicts.
>
> Spongy Castle is the stock Bouncy Castle libraries with a couple of small changes to make it work on Android:
>
> - all package names have been moved from org.bouncycastle.* to org.spongycastle.*
> - to avoid classloader conflicts the Java Security API Provider name is now SC rather than BC
> - no class names change, so the BouncyCastleProvider class remains Bouncy, not Spongy, but moves to the org.spongycastle.jce.provider package.

Comment: Recent versions of Android have renamed the bouncycastle classes that Android uses to something like com.android.org.bouncycastle.*, so this is no longer a problem, at least for those versions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you tell how recent?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Looking the sources, at least API 17 uses the "refactored" version you mentioned. I believe your comment could be an answer too.