# How to encrypt & decrypt using Camellia 128bit in Android JAVA code?

Tags: java, android, flutter, encryption, camellia

What is the provider name syntax for Camellia 128bit in Android JAVA code?? i try to change from `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")` into `Cipher.getInstance("Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding","BC")` but it says Provider BC does not provide "Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding". Below is my code

```
try {
      String keyString = "Potatoman55@";//length of key is 16
      Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding","BC");
      byte[] key = new byte[0];
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
              key = keyString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
          }
      }
      MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      key = sha.digest(key);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
          key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
      }

      SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
      desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

      String plainText = "hello wolrd";
      System.out.println("plaintext: "+plainText);

      byte[] text = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
      byte[] textencrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
      String textEnc = null;
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          System.out.println("encrypted: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(textencrypted));
          textEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(textencrypted);
      }
      result.success(textEnc);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully run the code by this code `new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());` as the provider. Big thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42352515/14562641) comment. below is the full syntax

```
Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding",new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```